# How to deploy a Linux Azure Function using the Github Docker Registry

Tags: azure, docker, github, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I cannot get a deployment of an Azure Function by private repository, using then new Github artifact repo for Docker to work (https://github.com/features/packages).

My linux_fx_version is:

```py
'linux_fx_version': 'DOCKER|{}'.format(self.docker_image_id)
```

with docker_image_id having the value `organisation`/`project-name`/`container-name`:latest

For the other settings, I am using

```py
                        { "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD",            "value": self.docker_password },
                        { "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME",            "value": self.docker_username },
                        { "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL",                 "value": self.docker_url },
```

with the docker_url being `https://docker.pkg.github.com/`, and the password being the token with `read:packages`

Things look good, and yet I get the following (I am not able to fetch any deployment logs as the runtime is unreachable).

```
Error:

Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable. Click here for details on storage configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

Use `https://docker.pkg.github.com/` as the docker URL,

and `docker.pkg.github.com/<org>/<project-name>/<container-name>:<version>` as the linux_fx_version